# What is the dollar file? I found my Netbeans project...Will my project not have any problems because I will delete it?

Tags: java, netbeans-8

What is the dollar file? I found my Netbeans project...Will my project not have any problems because I will delete it?

Eg.createEmployee.class
CreateEmployee$.class

Comment: Classes with dollars in the name are (typically) classes generated by the compiler, e.g. anonymous classes. It will break things if the JVM needs that class (which it probably does, that's why the compiler generated it).

Comment: Sure it is not `CreateEmployee$1.class`?

Comment: It is the file required for the project .Are you telling me not to delete it?

Comment: I will delete it?

Comment: In NetBeans, these files (which are required to run the application) are generally placed within the `build` sub-directory of the Project Directory for your particular application. If you delete them, your application will not run through the IDE unless you do a file save, or do a 'Compile & Repair', or you have the 'Compile & Run' feature enabled in which case, the compiler will just recreate them again. In any case, when the source code is compiled these file types are created. Best thing to do...Just ignore them and stay out of the `build` sub-directory.